# FFmpeg sidechaincompress give more importance to the sidechain

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Have two audio tracks—one to be used as background and other as main audio—and I want to compress and mix the background audio to the main.

I tried using the `sidechaincompress` filter but in the output the main audio volume is very low.

Comment: Show the command you used along with its console output.

Comment: ffmpeg -i background.mp3 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress[compr];[compr][mix]amerge[final]" -map [final] final.mp3

Comment: Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mp3) -> sidechaincompress:main
  Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> asplit
  amerge -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
size=     892kB time=00:00:57.05 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:892kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.027704%

Comment: Is the music drowning out the main audio, or is the main audio too low?

Comment: Audio is low can hear it but need to hear it more tham the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, sounds like the default settings of the sidechaincompress filter don't filter the background music enough.

Try

```
ffmpeg -i background.mp3 -i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.1:ratio=5[bg]; \
                        [bg][mix]amerge[fin‌​al]"
       -map [final] final.mp3
```

There are two variables I've added.

`threshold` specifies how loud the main audio has to be before the sidechain compressor alters the music track's volume. If the volume of the main track is low to begin with, this value may need to be reduced.

`ratio` determines how much the background audio is reduced. Default value is `2`, and `min,max` is `1,20`

Comment: Added a release filter also to the sidechain as in between the audio the background audio was spiking up

Comment: That's meant to happen, but yes, for short periods of silence, you don't want the music volume to oscillate.

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference in `ratio=1` versus `ratio=20` - each track seems equally loud? Or is that done in some other way? Love, ffmpeg newb.

Comment: Share your full command and log.

Answer (score 1):

I used this command and found that the ratio value is not making any difference in background volume.

```
ffmpeg -i video/60secs.mp3 -i audionews/WhyRashmiDesariIsScared.wav -filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.1:ratio=20[bg];  [bg][mix]amerge[fin‌​al]" -map "[final]" video/1.mp3
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i video/60secs.mp3 -i audionews/WhyRashmiDesariIsScared.wav  -filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.1:ratio=5[bg][bg][mix]amerge[fin‌​al]" -map [final] video/final.mp3
```